# highcharts plugin cakephp option for 3d not found

Tags: cakephp, highcharts

hello well I am doing a grafic for my system with [highcharts plugin cakephp](https://github.com/destinydriven/cakephp-high-charts-plugin) now the problem is that I am trying to do this grafic in 3d, highchart have this option but not found in my system, this is my code:

controller everything works fine but not in 3d

```
public function columnacompra($id = null)
    {
        $this->loadModel('Soya');
        $this->loadModel("SoyaProductorCompra");
        $years = $this->SoyaProductorCompra->getYears();
        $distinct_years = array();
        foreach($years as $year) {
            $distinct_years[] = $year[0]['distinct_year'];
        }
        $this->set(compact('distinct_years'));

        if (!$id) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Porfavor provea un id de usuario');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $user = $this->Soya->findById($id);
        if (!$user) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('El id proporcionado no es valido');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if (!$this->request->data) {
                $this->request->data = $user;
        }

        $SoyaMensual = array(120, 265, 245, 120, 265, 245,120, 265, 245,120, 265, 245);
        $SoyaDiario = array(120, 265, 245, 120, 265, 245,120, 265, 245,120, 265, 245);

        $chartName = 'Stacked Grouped Column Chart';

        $mychart = $this->HighCharts->create( $chartName, 'column' );

        $this->HighCharts->setChartParams(
            $chartName,
            array(
                'renderTo'          => 'columnwrapper',  // div to display chart inside
                'options3dEnabled' => true, //not found
                'chartWidth'            => 1000,
                'chartHeight'           => 750,
                'chartBackgroundColorLinearGradient'    => array(0,0,0,300),
                'chartBackgroundColorStops'     => array(array(0,'rgb(217, 217, 217)'),array(1,'rgb(255, 255, 255)')),
                'title'             => 'Tabla Comparativa',
                'subtitle'              => 'Soya Compras',
                'xAxisLabelsEnabled'        => TRUE,
                'xAxisCategories'           => array( 'Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'),
                'yAxisTitleText'        => 'Cantidad en (TM)',
                'enableAutoStep'        => FALSE,
                'creditsEnabled'        => FALSE,
                'plotOptionsSeriesStacking'     => 'normal'

            )
        );

        $johnSeries = $this->HighCharts->addChartSeries();
        $janeSeries = $this->HighCharts->addChartSeries();

        $johnSeries->addName('Mensual')
            ->addData($SoyaMensual)
            ->stack = 'compra';

        $janeSeries->addName('Diario')
            ->addData($SoyaDiario)
            ->stack = 'compra';


        $mychart->addSeries($johnSeries);
        $mychart->addSeries($janeSeries);



    }
```

view is here

```
<div class="actions">
<h3>Acciones</h3>
<ul>
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link( "Volver Atras",   array('action'=>'graficas', $this->data['Soya']['id'])); ?></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="chart">
    <h2>Tabla Comparativa de la cantidad de compras</h2>    

<?php echo $this->Html->script('modules/exporting');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('highcharts-3d');?>

    <div id="columnwrapper" style="display: block; float: left; width:90%; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>   

    <?php echo $this->HighCharts->render('Stacked Grouped Column Chart'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CakePHP Highcharts plugin](https://github.com/destinydriven/cakephp-high-charts-plugin) has been updated to support 3D charts as of a few days ago. You can find code examples on how to implement it within the plugin's demo code which is available on Github.

Here is how you would setup your controller action for a 3D column chart:

```
public function column3d() {

            $chartData = array(
                29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4
            );

            $chartName = 'Column 3D Chart';

            $mychart = $this->Highcharts->create($chartName, 'column');

            $this->Highcharts->setChartParams($chartName, array(
                'renderTo' => 'column3dwrapper', // div to display chart inside
                'chartWidth' => 1000,
                'chartHeight' => 750,
                'title' => '3D Column Chart Demo',
                'subtitle' => 'Source: World Bank',
                'options3d' => array(
                    'enabled' => true,
                    'alpha' => 15,
                    'beta' => 15,
                    'depth' => 50,
                    'viewDistance' => 25
                ),
                'xAxisLabelsEnabled' => true,
                'yAxisTitleText' => 'Units',
                'enableAutoStep' => false,
                'creditsEnabled' => false,
                )
            );

            $series = $this->Highcharts->addChartSeries();

            $series->addName('3D Series')
                    ->addData($chartData);

            $mychart->addSeries($series);

            $this->set(compact('chartName'));
    }
```

In your column3d.ctp view file you would the following:

```
<div class="chart">
    <h4>Column 3D Chart</h4>

    <div id="column3dwrapper" style="display: block; float: left; width:90%; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>   

    <?php echo $this->Highcharts->render($chartName); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their code, CakePHP is using 3.x version, while 3D charts were introduced in 4.x version. I guess then it's not supported.